# Ruby on rails Merge two routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have the controller named collection and the model name products.
The collection page is showing all the products.
Here is the code that show's the products

```
<% @products.each do |x| %>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="product-container animated fadeIn">
      <div class="product-image-holder">
        <%= image_tag x.image1.url(:fhd) %>
      </div>
      <div class="product-title-holder">
        <span class="product-title"><%= x.title %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now i want to wrap each product in it's own link ( link to single product )
i managed to do that but the link will be www.localhost.com/product/1 instead of this i want to be www.localhost.com/collection/product/1
Any help ? :)

This are the routes

```
  get 'collection', to:'collection#index'
  resources :product
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `scope`

```
scope '/collection' do
  resources :products
end
```

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing